# JUnit test debuging hangs in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, junit, intellij-idea

During debugging the test code it hangs on the initialization phase. 
The latest message at the log is (before the debugging hangs):

`2013-03-15 13:03:09:215 INFO [          :          ] [main:o.h.d.Dialect] Using dialect: my.company.package.util.hibernate.HSQLDialect`

Please consider the following factors which seems to impact the debugging:

- Test runs with `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)`
- Test run on IntelliJ IDEA 12.0.4
- When tests run without debugging they works without any problems

What to do to debug the code?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Make sure you did not place a breakpoint on method signature instead of line of regular code. You can recognize such breakpoint also by 4 black dots inside red circle. They slow down debugging dramatically.

Comment: Inspect all of them using breakpoints list - it's easy to create one incidentally.

Comment: Yes, they WERE placed! Not it test classes but in some beans. Thank you, now it works.

Comment: I have the same problem in Android Studio 2.3, and removing breakpoints is not the solution because in previous releases I could add lots of breakpoints whenever I like, even when tests were building, and IDE was not hanging. Something went wrong with latest update.

Answer (score 2):

Try to remove all breakpoints and restart your Debug.
Press Command+Shift+F8, then Command+A and press Del. This if for Mac.

Answer (score 0):

It could easily be that you need to supply the test with more PermGen space.

Try using this in your configurations for that test:

```
-XX:MaxPermSize=300m
```

If your tests aren't insanely huge (and they shouldn't be), this should be more than enough.

Comment: It's already bigger: `-XX:MaxPermSize=500m`. My tests are not so big, may be it's because of Spring?

Comment: I have expanded the size, but it still dosn't work `-XX:MaxPermSize=1000m`